# Difference between TileStache and Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geojson, tilestache, vector-tiles

I have troubles to understand the differences between TileStache and Geoserver.

My goal is to serve tiled geoJson through a restFull API and consume it with Leafet.

Which one is the best for this use case? Is one faster than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geoserver is an OGC compliant Web server which can serve out data in OGC's web services, namely WMS, WFS & WCS.

You want to get GeoJSON Tiles, and use it in your Leaflet Map. GeoJSON tiles are not a OGC standard, and GeoServer can not serve out GeoJSON Tiles.

TileStache on the other hand, [can serve out GeoJSON Tiles](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Vector.html) from ESRI Shapefile, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Spatialite and GeoJSON data sources.

You can have your data in one of these formats/Databases, and then serve out vector tiles using TileStache.

This is an article I found with a quick Google Search, which shows how to serve out Tiled GeoJSON: [TileStache: Generate [Topo|Geo]JSON Vector Tiles](http://mattmakesmaps.com/blog/2013/10/09/tilestache-rendering-topojson/)

You can show these GeoJSON tiles in Leaflet with a plugin like [leaflet-tilelayer-geojson](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson)

Comment: Just an update:  since this answer was written, GeoServer has gained the ability to server vector tiles.  See this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203878/can-not-find-application-jsontype-geojson-in-geoserver-tile-cache-format/203881#203881