# Can not find "application/json;type=geojson" in Geoserver Tile cache format

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, wmts

I want to server TMS service using `geoserver`. I know it can be done using `GeoWebCache` which is loaded by default on `geoserver`, I have downloaded last version of `geoserver` and installed it,there must be `'application/json;type=geojson'` in Geoserver Tile cache format, but there is not any,for example [this](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/vectortiles/index.html) tutorial shows it

[image]

So, why can't I find it in geoserver admin. Should I do anything else?

Comment: did you install the vector tiles extension?

Comment: @iant not in fact,Is it an extention?where can i find it?

Comment: Vector tile production is very new to Geoserver and is not yet well documented. I am doing research on the same topic since a week and there is not official documentation from GeoServer on this topic yet. Next official version will probably have some answers.

Comment: @Camilo yes and it is very useful too,I hope they document it quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably mixing up a tutorial for the OpenGeo Suite with an official GeoServer (the suite contains a modified one, different style, extra non default plugins, don't know if there are other changes).

It seems you are trying to get vector tiles going, in the official GeoServer that's an unsupported module that you can download from the nightly builds: 
http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/

Pick the series you want to use, go in community-latest, search for vectortiles-plugin.

Comment: thanks very much,do you have any tutorial about running that plugin?I've installed it,but does not show any thing when I select geojson

Comment: The GeoServer community has none (the module, as said above, is not supported). I don't know if the OpenGeo suite contains any.

Comment: thsnks so much.I am trying to make it work but could not yet